# no se me agregan todas clases al instalar tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind, framework

al momento de instalar  tailwindcss en mi proyecto no se cargan todas las clases como por nombrar 1 ejemplo mr-2 o pb-3.
pero si me carga las generales como m-4 o p-3.
al ejecutar este comando me arroja siempre esta alerta

```
npx tailwindcss -o public/css/style.css --watch
```

warn - The `content` key is missing or empty. Please populate the content key as Tailwind generates utilities on-demand based on the files that use them.

alguien me puede ayudar con una guia para realizar una instalacion limpia?
he seguido varias pero siempre tengo el mismo resultado...

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, se me instala hasta la linea 700 aproximado, he intentado varias veces y no hay caso que se instale correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Minifica el archivo de salida, agrega el flag `--minify`:

```
npx tailwindcss -o public/css/style.css --watch --minify`
```

Comment: Al lado de `--minify` hay un caracter extra: ¿es un _typo_? De ser así, por favor, corrígelo. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio (y así ganar tu primera [medalla](/help/badges)) y lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la propiedad `content` de tu archivo de configuración. Tiene que hacer referencia a tu archivo `index.html` para que tome las clases.

Desde la versión 3 del framework ya no te trae todas las clases con las instalación sino que lo maneja con variables css y va añadiendo solo las clases que añadas para optimizar todo.